# How can I add 'emacs' to one of the 'Show other application' in file explorer

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, emacs

In file explorer (Nautilus) under Ubuntu, I can select a file and right click and scroll to:

> open with other application

My question is how can I add `emacs` to that list of "*other application*"

Comment: Which emacs package do you have installed? Also, what type of file are you expecting to see this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After we had installed [emacs](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/emacs) [image: Install emacs] we may not yet have a .desktop file to integrate it with the desktop environment.

We then can copy the `emacs23.desktop` file if located in `/usr/share/applications` or we can create a custom emacs.desktop file in `~.local/share/applications`, e.g. with the following content (add further options at your needs).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Emacs 23
Comment=
Exec=/usr/bin/emacs23 %F
Icon=
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

We can then select Emacs in the list of *"Open With Other Applications -> Show other applications"* on right click of a file with a content we want to associate Emacs with.

[image]

After having selected the now present Emacs (note that there is no icon defined yet if using a custom dektop file, give the path to an icon in your emacs.desktop above) we can then choose to *"Open with Emacs"* in the Nautilus context menu:

[image]

To undo this we simply right click on the Emacs entry in the menu that pops up after having selected *"Open With Other Application..."* and say *"Forget association"*:
(Forget association option does not exist for Ubuntu 16.04 and later)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I couldn't get this working before. I was missing the `%F` flag in my `emacs.desktop` file.

Answer (score 0):

I use emacs-snapshot  available [here](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs) (the latest release, good if you want to extend your environment with additional packages) and this is my `~/.local/share/applications/emacs-snapshot.desktop` entry that adds files into the existing emacs instance as a new buffer instead of creating a new window every time (way faster and you can easily switch using `C-x b` - even cooler with [IDO-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) enabled).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Emacs-kermit
Version=1.0
GenericName=Emacs
Comment=GNU Emacs Snapshot Client
Exec=/usr/bin/emacsclient.emacs-snapshot -a 'emacs' %F
TryExec=emacs-snapshot
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=emacs-snapshot
Categories=Development;Utility;TextEditor;
MimeType=text/plain;
```

Note that for emacsclient to work, you need to have this in your `~/.emacs` configuration file:

```
(load "server")
(unless (server-running-p) (server-start))
```